# Django - [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, django

I have this error and I don't know the reason :

This error is in my console :

```
[05/Jul/2015 15:42:35] "POST /suppression-demande HTTP/1.1" 200 4262
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
self.finish_response()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 212, in write
self.send_headers()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 270, in send_headers
self.send_preamble()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 194, in send_preamble
'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
self.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[05/Jul/2015 15:42:35] "POST /suppression-demande HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

On click on a button, this JS methods is called :

```
function goto_confirm(username){
    adress = "/suppression-demande"
    if(confirm("Are you sure ?")){
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:adress,
             data: {
                    'confirmation_suppression': true,
             },
             success: function(data){
                 alert("data : "+data);
             }
        });

        window.location.href = "/home";
    }

    return false;
}
```

The URL :
    url(r'^suppression-demande$', 'supprimer_demande', name="supprimer_demande"),

My View called by js method :

```
def supprimer_demande(request):   
    confirmation = request.POST.get("confirmation_suppression")
    return render(request,"website/lsdme.html")
```

Comment: Try adding a slash after your URL.

Comment: I have the same error

Answer (score 3):

Try removing 
window.location.href = "/home"; 
from your js method go_confirm().

Comment: coz you are rendering from your view to  a different location while your function tells it to go to another. Would you mind accepting the answer? :D

Comment: Well you can't redirect to different locations.. =P

Comment: Or move it to `success`. The problem is that your browser closes the connection for the ajax request when it redirects, while Django still tries to send data.